# What are some best practices for searching a binary tree?

Tags: c, search, data-structures, struct, binary-tree

I'm learning about binary trees in C and I wrote a function to search my tree which is a tree of strings. It works, however, it seg faults if the string is not in the tree and I'm struggling to figure out how to error check it. It has me wondering if there are any best practices for searching through trees.

```
tnode *search(tnode *p, char *w)
{
    if (p->word == NULL || strcmp(w, p->word) == 0)
        return p;
    else if (strcmp(w, p->word) < 0)
        return search(p->left, w);
    else
        return search(p->right, w);
}
```

I've changed this function around a bunch but as long as it returns `NULL` it will fault. The best solution I can think of is to just have it return an `int` or `bool` or `char *` so I don't have to deal with returning a `NULL` struct.

Is there a way to make it work with this function or would it just be better to not have it return a struct?

Comment: What is `p->left` or `p->right` is NULL?  That may mean that the value is not in the tree.  Or perhaps a check of `p` itself for NULL.

Comment: Best practice is not to use a recursive function when there is a simple iterative solution. As long as `p` is not null, if `p->word` matches, return `p`, otherwise set `p` to `p->left` or `p->right` according to the comparison, and repeat. After the loop, return `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every node will have a left and a right child. Some will have neither, some will have one or the other. As such, if the value being searched isn't in the tree, the code will eventually call `search(NULL, w)`. This is unhandled.

Other improvements can be made:

- Someone might want to try to search an empty tree (`p == NULL`), so that should be checked. We'll take advantage of that same check to solve the main problem.
- It doesn't make sense to have a node with `NULL` for value (`p->word`), so there's no point in checking for that.
- It doesn't make sense to search for `NULL` either. We can avoid that check too.
- Let's avoid making the same call to `strcmp` twice.
- Let's mark the string as constant.

```c
tnode *search(tnode *p, const char *w) {
    if (p == NULL)
        return NULL;

    int cmp = strcmp(w, p->word);
    if      (cmp < 0) return search(p->left, w);
    else if (cmp > 0) return search(p->right, w);
    else              return p;
}
```

Finally, there's no reason to use recursion here.

```c
tnode *search(tnode *p, const char *w) {
    while (p != NULL) {
        int cmp = strcmp(w, p->word);
        if      (cmp < 0) p = p->left;
        else if (cmp > 0) p = p->right;
        else              return p;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say there is just a guard for **p** equal Null missing.

```
tnode*
search(tnode *p, char *w)
{
    if(p == NULL || w == NULL) return NULL;

    if (strcmp(w, p->word) == 0)
        return p;
    else if (strcmp(w, p->word) < 0)
        return search(p->left, w);
    else
        return search(p->right, w);
}
```

The calling function then has to check if **search()** returns Null (not found) or a pointer (the node).

The reason you get a segmentation fault is that, if the key is not in the tree then you call search() with Null. The first thing search() does is to retrieve word with **p->word** but p is not a valid address resulting in an exception.